# Seeking help in translation lyrics from the Chinese song

Tags: translation, meaning, lyrics

I'm trying to translate 光年之外 [Light Years Away] by G.E.M. (mostly from English though...) and in the first verse there's a line which I'm really curious about.

感受停在我发端的指尖

如何瞬间 冻结时间

**记住望着我坚定的双眼**

也许已经 没有明天

It's about the third one. I've found two translations online:

1. Remember to gaze at my unflinching eyes
2. I see a pair of eyes looking steadly at me
3. Remembering (I remember) the gaze looking firmly at me [*it's what I came up with]

Can anyone tell what exactly is this line about? And if anything from above is a good translation?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll modify your choice as:

- "**记住**"望着我"**坚定的**"双眼 - "Remember gaze/look at my staunch eyes." Or, "Don't forget to gaze/look into my staunch eyes."

Note, "remember (记住)" = "don't forget (別忘了)" by poetic interpretation. And, the choices for "坚定的" include "steadfast", "unwavering" and "unswerving".

Answer (score 0):

#3 is correct

"记住"(remember) is the verb

"望着我坚定的双眼" (the firm eyes that were looking at me) is the object

望着我的 and 坚定的 are the adjectives for 双眼

望着我的 坚定的 双眼 --> 望着我坚定的双眼

*Note 1: gaze is 目光; 双眼 is eyes*

*Note 2: if it is only 望着我坚定的双眼, then 望着 would be the verb and the sentence would mean "look at my unflinching eyes"*